# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/branch-A' by 12 commits

Tags: git, git-branch

This is a known problem on SO. The solution I believe is `git reset --hard origin/branch-A` (I am not 100% sure).

- I created a merge request from `branch-A` to `branch-B`. The changes got merged successfully to branch-B, no problem.
- I am currently on `branch-A`. On doing `git status` on command line, I am getting the following message:

  ```
  On branch branch-A
  Your branch is ahead of 'origin/branch-A' by 12 commits.
    (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
  ```

I am not sure where those 12 commits came from. What changes do I need to do in order to fix it?